# C# parse chemical formula WITH PARENTHESES

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I'm trying to write a C# chemical formula parser that extracts a chemical formula from a string input. I have figured out how to do this with chemical formulas that don't contain parentheses, such as H2O, etc. However, I have no clue how to make this work with parentheses, such as with a formula like Al2(HPO4)3.

Just a note, but this would output a list of classes known as "*FormulaComponents*" that have two variables, an Element (string), and a number.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's my current attempt. It handles everything short of parentheses.

```
public static Formula Parse(string input)
{
    var components = new List<FormulaComponent>();

    const string elementRegex = "([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]*)";
    const string validateRegex = "^(" + elementRegex + ")+$";

    if (!Regex.IsMatch(input, validateRegex))
        throw new FormatException("Input string was in an incorrect format.");

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, elementRegex))
    {
        var name = match.Groups[1].Value;

        var count = match.Groups[2].Value != "" ?
            int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value) :
            1;

        if (ElementManager.FindElementBySymbol(name) == null)
            throw new FormatException(name + " is not recognized as a valid element symbol.");

        components.Add(new FormulaComponent { Element = ElementManager.FindElementBySymbol(name), Quantity = count });
    }

    return new Formula { Components = components };
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output? Do you want to ignore parentheses or count it as only one component? Also post what you've already tried.

Comment: I'm hoping to basically "distribute" the number outside of the parentheses. For example, with Al2(HPO4)3, it would produce the components (Al, 2), (H, 3), (P, 3), (O, 12). I'll add my current attempt right now.

Comment: Wait, wait, the input is not natural text "I like H2O", but actually a chemical compound already, and you would like to transform it to list of atoms (what compound is made of). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is an overkill, but at least it is clean -- you can use lexer+parser to do the job.

Lexer rules:

```
/[A-Z][a-z]*/ -> ATOM;
/[0-9]+/ -> NUM, Convert.ToInt32($text);
"(" -> LPAREN;
")" -> RPAREN;
```

And parser rules:

```
s -> c:comp { c };

atom -> a:ATOM { new Atom(a,1) }
      | a:ATOM n:NUM { new Atom(a,n) }
      ;

comp -> LPAREN c:comp RPAREN n:NUM { new Compound(c,n) }
      | c:comp+ { new Compounds(c) }
      | a:atom { a }
      ;
```

Those are just the rules (I didn't test anything here). If you like you can use my [NLT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/) lexer+parser, but there are plenty of other such tools for C# -- pick your favorite.

*Since you don't have nested parentheses, regexes might be easier for you.*

Comment: Thank you... I'll try and figure this out in a bit.

Comment: @CreeperInATardis, for the record I just added parsing chemical formula as an example in NLT and (oddly?) the working grammar is not far from the one above.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what your Formula class looks like, I put the results into a MessageBox

```
    public static Double getElements(String _molecule)
    {
        Boolean useParenthesis = Regex.IsMatch(_molecule, @"[A-Z][a-z]?\d*\((([A-Z][a-z]?\d*){1,2})\)\d*");
        var findMatches = Regex.Matches(_molecule, @"\(?[A-Z][a-z]?\d*\)?"); // Get all elements
        if (useParenthesis)
        {
            Double endNumber = Double.Parse(Regex.IsMatch(_molecule, @"\)\d+") ? Regex.Match(_molecule, @"\)\d+").Value.Remove(0, 1) : "1"); // Finds the number after the ')'
            foreach (Match i in findMatches)
            {
                String element = Regex.Match(i.Value, "[A-Z][a-z]?").Value; // Gets the element
                Double amountOfElement = 0;
                if (Regex.IsMatch(i.Value, @"[\(\)]"))
                {
                    if (!Double.TryParse(Regex.Replace(i.Value, @"(\(|\)|[A-Z]|[a-z])", ""), out amountOfElement))
                        amountOfElement = endNumber; // If the element has either '(' or ')' and doesn't specify an amount, then set it equal to the endnumber
                    else
                        amountOfElement *= endNumber; // If the element has either '(' or ')' and specifies an amount, then multiply it by the end number
                }
                else
                    amountOfElement = Double.Parse(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.Value.Replace(element, "")) ? "1" : i.Value.Replace(element, ""));
                MessageBox.Show(element + " - " + amountOfElement);
            }
            return endNumber;
        }
        else
            return 0.0;
    }
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but there's the potential of unbalanced parentheses. That is, it looks like your regex will allow something like `HPO4)3` (i.e. missing the opening paren).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have this regular expression:

```
`"(([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]*)) |
  ((\()?([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]*)(\)[0-9]*)?)"`
```

That matches either H2O, or (HPO4)3.

When you get your match, you can parse out the trailing digit (if any), and run the regex again on the parts in parentheses. Something like:

```
foreach (var match in regex.Matches(line))
{
    if (match.Value[0] == '(')
    {
        // get the number from the end
        var multiplier = match.Groups[whatever];  // whatever group index that is
        // get the formula inside parentheses
        var formula = match.Groups[formulaIndex]; // again, whatever group index
        foreach (var match2 in regex.Matches(formula))
        {
            // parse that as a normal formula (i.e. not in parentheses)
            // remember to multiply by your multiplier
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // parse it as a normal formula
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to make that `parse as a normal formula` a separate method so you're not duplicating code. Or, you could potentially make the parsing bit recursive, so that the inner `foreach` loop calls the method again. You'd almost certainly have to do that if you need to handle nested parentheses.